# Determinar execução conforme página de origem

Tags: php

Existe alguma maneira de definir uma determinada ação conforme a página de origem?

Ex: se a página anterior for `exibir.php` executar "x" ou se a página anterior for `inserir.php` executar "y".

Comment: Qual é o objetivo disso ? Acredito que há melhores formas de se fazer.

Comment: um jeito mais seguro é usando session ou mesmo cookies client side..

Comment: Eu nem entendi o problema...

Comment: Na pagina anterior faz um session pra registrar a pagina anterior e na nova pagina.. faz um if($_SESSION[x]=='exibir.php'){ exibe tal pag } else { exibe outra pag }

Comment: Obrigado André Baill !!

Comment: @AndréBaill faça uma resposta.

Comment: Ok feito. @Victoralm se puder fazer a gentileza de dar um aceite na minha resposta. Grato! :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Faça da seguinte forma:

Na página anterior:

```
session_register("pagina_atual");
```

E na nova página:

```
if($_SESSION['pagina_atual']=="exibir"){
pagina exibir
} else {
pagina outra
}
```

Comment: [`session_register`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-register.php) é uma função antiga que até já foi retirada do PHP a partir da 5.4. Refaça sua resposta por favor.

Answer (score 1):

Como as requisições HTTP são isoladas, precisamos utilizar de outros recursos para apontar a página de origem. Todas elas envolvem em definir um identificador da página de origem que será passado para a página seguinte.

Algumas alternativas que podem ser exploradas incluem (cabe a você decidir qual utilizar em cada caso):

1. Uso de sessions

Origem:

```
<?php 

session_start();
$_SESSION['origem'] = "paginaOrigem";
```

Pagina Seguinte:

```
<?php

session_start();

if ($_SESSION['origem'] === "paginaOrigem"){

// ....

}
```

2. Usando cookies

Origem:

```
<?php 

setcookie('origem', 'PaginaOrigem');
```

Pagina Seguinte:

```
<?php


if ($_COOKIE['origem'] === "paginaOrigem"){

// ....

}
```

3. Usando parâmetros de URL (caso seja um link)

Origem:

```
<a href="paginaDestino.php?origem=paginaOrigem">Link</a>
```

Pagina Seguinte:

```
<?php


if ($_GET['origem'] === "paginaOrigem"){

// ....

}
```

4. Usando um campo no `hidden` no form (caso seja um `POST`)

Origem:

```
<input type="hidden" name="origem" value="paginaOrigem">
```

Pagina Seguinte:

```
<?php


if ($_POST['origem'] === "paginaOrigem"){

// ....

}
```

**Considerações:** Utilizar o `GET` (parâmetro por URL) é o mais fácil de ser manipulado.

Ao utilizar sessions ou cookies, procure limpar o conteúdo da variável após a requisição da página de origem, pois isso pode fazer que a página seguinte execute a mesma ação duas vezes e fique alguma "sujeira"

```
<?php


if ($_COOKIE['origem'] === "paginaOrigem"){

// ....

}

// Terminou de executar tudo?
setcookie('origem', null, -1);
// Ou em caso de Session
unset($_SESSION['origem']);
```